# Cannot run program "sh" eclipse C++ project in windows 7

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows

I'm on Eclipse Luna for C/C++ developers. Compiling a Hello World project works just fine. But now I'm working with a project I downloaded via SVN and can't get it to build correctly.

The problem shows "CreateProcess error = 2 the system cannot find the specified file" Type: Configure Problem.

From what I've looked up this is caused by having configured an Autotools project, but in C/C++ build -> Tool Chain Editor -> Current Toolchain I have set up MinGW GCC instead of GNU Autotools toolchain. Any ideas on what could be causing this problem or how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have MSys properly installed, and appearing in your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @Nicolas have you solved your problem ?